# Why this thread(WriteData) not doing it's functionality?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm practising Semaphore class 
I've created two threads of which one writes the data to the HashMap in "Shared" class and the other reads the data from the Shared class.

So my problem is when I'm reading the data it only shows the data which was previously added in Shared class, Not the updated data. I have no clue where I'm missing.

Should I read from "Writedata" class if so How a thread return HashMap.

```
class Shared {

    Map<String, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    {
        hashmap.put("kishore", 797979);
        hashmap.put("nanesg", 8768787);
        hashmap.put("mahesh", 842803);
        hashmap.put("srikar", 7979980);
    }

    public void puthash(String name, Integer in, Map<String, Integer> hashmap) {
        hashmap.put(name, in);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> gethash() {
        return this.hashmap;
    }

}

class ReadHashMap implements Runnable {

    Semaphore sem;
    String name;
    Shared shared = new Shared();

    ReadHashMap(Semaphore sem, String name) {
        this.sem = sem;
        this.name = name;

        new Thread(this, name).start();

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Thread trying to acquiring the permit ");
            sem.acquire();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Thread acquires the permit ");
            Map<String, Integer> hashmap = shared.gethash();
            Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = hashmap.entrySet();
            System.out.println("reading data in hashmap, Here is the data: ");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> mp : set) {

                System.out.println(mp.getKey() + "  : " + mp.getValue());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Thread relesing the permit ");
            sem.release();
        }

    }
}

class WriteData implements Runnable {

    Semaphore sem;
    String name;
    Shared shared = new Shared();

    WriteData(Semaphore sem, String name) {
        this.sem = sem;
        this.name = name;
        new Thread(this, name).start();

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Thread trying to get permit");
            sem.acquire();
            Map<String, Integer> hashmap = shared.gethash();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Thread acquires the permit ");
            shared.puthash("added1", 98799, hashmap);
            shared.puthash("added2", 987989, hashmap);
            shared.puthash("added3", 98979, hashmap);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Thread relesing the permit ");
        sem.release();
    }
}

public class SemaphoreDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

        new WriteData(sem, "write");
        new ReadHashMap(sem, "read");
    }
}
```

Here is It's Output:

```
writeThread trying to get permit
read Thread trying to acquiring the permit 
write Thread acquires the permit 
write Thread relesing the permit 
read Thread acquires the permit 
reading data in hashmap, Here is the data: 
nanesg  : 8768787
mahesh  : 842803
kishore  : 797979
srikar  : 7979980
read Thread relesing the permit
```

why the WriteData thread(specifically the function) is not adding the data. What was wrong with that function?

Comment: You have a class named "Shared", but each thread creates its own instance. Nothing actually is shared by the two threads except for the `Semaphore` object created in your `main()` routine.

Comment: yeah! got it. solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you created different `Shared` instances in `ReadHashMap` and `WriteData`.

### Solution

Use the same `Shared`:

```
class ReadHashMap implements Runnable {

    Semaphore sem;
    String name;
    Shared shared;

    ReadHashMap(Semaphore sem, String name, Shared shared) {
        this.sem = sem;
        this.name = name;
        this.shared = shared;
        new Thread(this, name).start();
    }
    ....
}

class WriteData implements Runnable {

    Semaphore sem;
    String name;
    Shared shared;

    WriteData(Semaphore sem, String name, Shared shared) {
        this.sem = sem;
        this.name = name;
        this.shared = shared;
        new Thread(this, name).start();
    }

    ....
}

public class SemaphoreDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
        Shared shared = new Shared();

        new WriteData(sem, "write", shared);
        new ReadHashMap(sem, "read", shared);
    }
}
```

### Result

```
writeThread trying to get permit
write Thread acquires the permit 
read Thread trying to acquiring the permit 
write Thread relesing the permit 
read Thread acquires the permit 
reading data in hashmap, Here is the data: 
nanesg  : 8768787
mahesh  : 842803
kishore  : 797979
added2  : 987989
added3  : 98979
srikar  : 7979980
added1  : 98799
read Thread relesing the permit
```